# HTTP Post with no body in Angular

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular-http

I'm wondering how to send an HTTP post request without a body (specifically in Angular). Here's what I'm doing now, but I'm getting the error `Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1)`.

I realize the second argument is for the body, but I'm not sending that to the server (yes, I understand that a POST call changes the state of a system and have looked into [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191593/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-perform-http-post-without-entity-body) question).

```
postRequest(id) {
  this.http.post('/api?data=' + id).map(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Just send an empty object

Comment: very good answer @Antikhippe. you have to add a `body` even if it is empty , undefined etc.

Comment: No, that's actually not a good answer. Passing an empty object will not post a request without body. It will post a request with a body containing an empty JSON object (`{}`). Pass null.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this Request though? What are you expecting in the backend from POSTing to this `/api?data=` route?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Please see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191593/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-perform-http-post-without-entity-body) question as mentioned in my original post.

Comment: My bad, oversaw that resource. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I had a similar problem and my issue was I didn't subscribe to the observable. The POST was meant as a command so nothing was returned.  Still need to subscribe to get it to execute.

Comment: Use .subscribe(); Found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077714/angular-sending-post-request-with-empty-request-body

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Looks like this is the appropriate answer:

```
postRequest(id) {
  this.http.post('/api?data=' + id, null).map(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If `null` is not working (4XX error client side), try with `{}` JSON:

```
postRequest(id) {
    this.http.post('/api?data=' + id, {}).map((response) => {return response;});
}
```

Comment: null may not solve. I tried it and it does not solve. And, I think we need to send JSON anyhow. So, empty JSON file it is

Answer (score 4):

Go to definition of POST method using your IDE and you can see passing either `body: any | null` are the available inputs

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try to call HTTP 'Post' without passing a 'body', and got this error in Angular 6 -**

[image]

If we go to definition of POST method in **`client.d.ts`**, it shows that post method required either 'body' or 'null' value (e.g. - body: any | null)-

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
...
}): Observable<Object>;
```

**Solution -** I just added 'null' and the error gone -

```
postSync(): any {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/xyz/sync-api`, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If request body is not there for post or put method then send empty object to request.
ex: {}.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment the accepted answer, so I'll just add that passing null is not sufficient, because the content type will not be inferred correctly and you may receive a 415 (at least that was my case). Use the options on http.post to specify the content type in the header and force json with the null body

```
this.http.post<T>(url, null, {
 headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
});
```