# Angular: Sending POST request with empty request body

Tags: angular, post

I am making a angular POST call to a backend service. Usecase is such that request has no body, so I do like :

```
http.post("my/backend/service", null);
```

I observe that endpoint is not hit, and there is also no error.

Is this not the correct way of handling empty request body for POST?

Comment: Have you looked at the Network tab of your browser to see if the POST request is made to the server? Have you tried an empty string? `http.post("my/backend/service", "");`?

Comment: Yeah, in network tab I don't see any POST request made. I haven't tried with "" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post` method return an `Observable` so you need either to `subscribe` to the `post` method or return the `Observable` and `subscribe` to your method.
Calling the `post` method and getting the `Observable` is like preparing the request, subscribing to the Observable is like runing the query.

```js
http.post("my/backend/service", null).subscribe();
```

You can find more about it in the [last section of this Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server).

> Because the service method returns an Observable of configuration data, the component subscribes to the method's return value.

The example use the `get()` method, but the problem come from the type of the response: `Observable`.

Comment: But subscribe is needed to do some operation after request has been served.I don't have to do anything. Do I still need to subscribe?

Comment: Do you have a reference that says that `post()` will not send a request unless there is a `subscribe`?

Comment: @Mandroid `subscribe` is needed in order to get the code executed. Without `subscribe` you only create an observable, he will never execute itself. Just try it and you will see the request in the Network tab.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have added details to my answer with a source.

Answer (score 0):

Send empty JSON object, May be it will work.

```
http.post("my/backend/service", {});
```